# VS 2005 winforms designer makes unrelated changes to source and resource files

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, designer

The Visual Studio 2005 Forms Designer automatically reorders statements in it's generated form.cs.designer file. This makes code reviews and svn logs quite useless for UI issues as a little change is lost in the countless auto-generated ones. Same goes for the auto-generated .resx files.

I'm sure this issue has been annoying more than just my team. Anyone knows a fix for this behavior?

Thanks! :)

Btw, I tried turning off the option "Tools -> Options -> Windows Forms Designer -> Optimized code generation", but it didn't change a thing.

related : [Visual Studio Designer is always trying to change my control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795678/visual-studio-designer-is-always-trying-to-change-my-control)